# Menu doesn't just stick to the specific product page

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, shopify, web-development-server

I'm experiencing a specific issue on my Shopify store related to menu navigation on mobile devices. I would like to prevent users from scrolling down the mobile page when the navigation menu is open on devices.

The problem only occurs on mobile devices, on the specific products page located at: https://gatte.com.br/products/hand-grip-pro. When opening the navigation menu on this page, users can still scroll down the page, which causes an unwanted user experience. My goal is to block page scrolling when the navigation menu is open, allowing users to only navigate through the menu without scrolling the page.

I'm wondering if anyone has experienced this particular issue with menu-navigation on mobile devices, especially on the specific product page mentioned above, and if there are any known workarounds to prevent the page from scrolling when menu-navigation is open in these situations.

I'm using the sense theme on Shopify, and the menu-navigation is built with custom HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Please rate in advance for any help or suggestions that might resolve this issue.

Here's what I've tried so far without success:

I added the CSS properties overflow: hidden and position: fixed to the  element, hoping to block page scrolling. Unfortunately, this solution did not produce the desired results either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be "the" solution, because there is a lot of conflicting CSS going on. However, you are doing what you need to already.

There are 2 CSS properties that is blocking you right now. Now I don't know how your website works and why these 2 properties are required in the first place but after unchecking these 2 properties and I was able to do what you asked for.

Comment out or remove the following in your CSS.

```css
html.gemapp.video {
  /* overflow y: auto!important; padding-bottom: 0!important; */
}

body.gempage {
  /* overflow y: auto!important; padding-bottom: 0!important; */
}
```

Comment: Do not post images of code, it will be easier for future readers to read and copy answers with codeblocks. (Links to images may break in future)